# Added m2 drive to my system. Already had cheap SSD for OS. Worth reinstalling OS to m2?

Tags: ssd, nvme

I have just added a 'Rocket NVMe M.2 2280 SSD' to my machine (Z97x Killer).

Until now I have cheap 120GB SSD + 500GB HDD. The OS is on the SSD.

Will I see any noticable performance change from reinstalling Windows to the NVME drive?

Or would it be better (or the same) to just use the NVMe drive to store my large games and project files for my work?

(NB. I ask this now, so that I can avoid adding more stuff to the storage only to later decide to wipe the machine to install the OS on the new drive)

Comment: You are already using the proper drive.  It's not necessary to reinstall Windows.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Seemed like it might have been better to use M2 for the OS

Comment: You could also just clone your Windows installation to the larger SSD.  It took me awhile to understand what you actually were asking.

Comment: ok I see yes. I have done that in past once. Last time I bought SSD, the new drive was smaller than the 'OS drive' but this time I don't have that problem

Comment: You would simply create an image of the smaller SSD, restore that image on the larger SSD, then change the boot order of your system.  You could then use the smaller SSD as a cache drive.  My original comment was suppose to say "driver" not "drive" by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you'll see much difference short-term, but over longer periods the tiny SSD is going to struggle with re-writes, as it gets fuller. You'll either spend more & more time farming data off to the large drive, or Trimming it more aggressively as space runs out.

I'd shift the OS & your 'working life' to the the new drive, keep the tiny old one around & use as a scratch disk or for caching, & the old spinny rust as a backup.

Personally, I'd clone the old drive to the new rather than start over, but I'm on Mac where this is a very simple task. IDK how efficient it is on Windows, I don't use it enough. Last time I cloned a Windows machine I did it on my Mac ;)